# Get the line number in yaml file in groovy

Tags: groovy, yaml

Is it possible to get line number of yaml file of the key values.

Let say

```
Key1: value
Key2: value2
Key3: value3
```

Now I need to get the key and associated value and line number of the key value pair.

Is any library or any existing method I can use to get the line number of the key value pair

Comment: Never seen this. Why do you need it?

Comment: Its requirement from customer. There are updating the yaml file frequently. If any issue happens while processing, they want the line number, so that they can go and update the right value.

Comment: Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** here for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the key-value pairs reside on the same line (because in general in the YAML file it does have to be on the same line to be a valid YAML) you don't have to parse the YAML file to get what you want. You can treat the file like a simple text file:

```java
new File('file.yaml').text.lines().eachWithIndex { String line, int lineNo ->
    if (line.contains('Key2') && line.contains('value2')) {
        println "Found matching $line on line $lineNo"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming one pair per line, the following sample would work:

```
def yaml = new groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper().parseText '''\
Key1: value
Key2: value2
Key3: value3
'''

String val = yaml.Key3
int line = yaml.entrySet().findIndexOf{ it.key == 'Key3' }

assert val == 'value3'
assert line == 2
```